# How many $7$-digit numbers can be formed if $3$ digits are the same and the rest are different (number cannot start with $0$ or $8$)?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $7$-digit numbers can be formed if $3$ digits are the same and the rest are different (number cannot start with $0$ or $8$)?

How am I trying to solve it:

1. All numbers: $10^7$
2. $5$ numbers are different: $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$
3. $2$ numbers are the same as one of those $5$ (it gives us $3$ numbers that are the same): $5$
4. Numbers cannot start from $0$ and $8$, so: all numbers -
   $\frac{10^7}{10} - \frac{10^7}{10}$:
   $$ 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 + 5 -  \frac{10^7}{10} - \frac{10^7}{10}$$

But I'm not sure at least about 3rd point..

Can anyone look at my answer, check my logic and help me to solve this?

Comment: Why did you add $5$ rather than multiplying by $5$?  You add when two tasks cannot both be performed; you multiply when they can be performed simultaneously.  The bigger issue is with your attempt to exclude numbers which begin with $0$ or $8$ since you did not account for the other conditions when you did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for all the constraints.  In particular, you need to consider the first three constraints when you remove those numbers that begin with $0$ or $8$.  Also, if you choose which five digits are to appear in the number, there are five ways to choose the repeated digit for each choice, so you should have multiplied rather than added.

**Method 1**:  One way to handle this problem is to consider cases depending on whether or not the leading digit is the repeated digit.

*The leading digit is the repeated digit*:  Since the leading digit cannot be zero or eight, we can choose it in eight ways.  We must also choose two of the remaining six positions for that digit.  We must choose four of the remaining nine digits to fill the remaining four positions, then arrange those four digits in those positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{8}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{9}{4}4!$$
such numbers.

*The leading digit is not the repeated digit*:  There are eight ways to choose the leading digit.  There are nine ways to choose the digit that appears three times.  We must choose three of the remaining six positions for that digit.  We must also choose three of the remaining eight digits to fill the remaining three positions and arrange those three digits in those positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{8}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{8}{3}3!$$
such numbers.

*Total*:  Since the two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of admissible seven-digit numbers is
$$\binom{8}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{9}{4}4! + \binom{8}{1}\binom{9}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{8}{3}3!$$

**Method 2:**  We initially ignore the constraint on the leading digit, then use symmetry.

Ignoring the constraint on the leading digit gives us ten choices for the digit that appears three times.  We must choose which three of the seven positions it fills.  We must also choose four of the remaining nine digits to fill the remaining four positions, then arrange them in those positions.  Finally, we must multiply by $8/10$ since only eight of the ten digits can be placed in the leading position, which yields
$$\frac{8}{10}\binom{10}{1}\binom{7}{3}\binom{9}{4}4!$$

Comment: Thank you very much!